# How to prevent code analysis dlls to be published on production server?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2019, code-analysis, publishing, netcoreapp3.1

When publishing an ASP.NET Core 3 API *netcoreapp3.1* project with Visual studio 2019, several code analysis dlls are published too. Moreover the dlls are published in 13 languages plus the english version.

How can I prevent Visual Studio from publishing code analysis dlls on the production server including the english version?

The dlls are:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.resources.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.resources.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.resources.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.resources.dll
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.4.5 on Window 10.

The publish configuration is:

```
Configuration: Release x64
Target framework: netcoreapp3.1
Deployment mode: Framework dependent
Target runtime: win-x64

File Publish Options:
Produce single file: no
Enable ReadyToRun compilation: yes
Delete all existing files prior to publish: yes
```

Comment: There are necessary for SQL to LINQ so if you don't include Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core, they won't be included.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 So if I rely on Entity Framework then this "baggage" is included ?

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto, I believe so but you could confirm but starting a project without and seeing if the libraries are still included.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 Uh, I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and was able to resolve it using the following method.You may change the project configuration adding ExcludeAssets to the following reference:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" ExcludeAssets="All"/>
```

When published like this I don't see the folders and dlls anymore.